# Finding a CDF for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {Y}_{i}$

Tags: probability

$X_1$, ..., $X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with cdf $F_X(x)$ and $E[X_i] = \mu$. Now let the random variable $Y$ be $$Y = 1,\ if \ X > \mu \\ Y = 0,\ if \ X \leqslant \mu$$ Find the CDF of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$.

So I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$ is the number of $X_i$'s that are under $\mu$. But how do I put it in random variable form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$Pr(Y=1)=Pr (X> \mu)=1-F_x(\mu)$

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is a binomial distribution with success probability $1-F_X(\mu)$

Comment: I found the CDF. Calling $Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, it's $$Pr(Q \leqslant q) = \sum_{k=0}^{q} \binom{n}{k} {(1-F_X(\mu))}^{k} {(F_X(\mu))}^{n-k}$$